# Checking if any data exists on a presumably empty storage device

Tags: linux, grep, dd, wipe

So, say you've completed a full pass of:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=1M
```

Then, you'd like to make sure the destination has been really *zeroed* out (ignoring the confirmation messages from `dd` and not just polling the start or the end of the device). Assuming that you'd have to read through the whole disk – I'd use this:

```
dd if=/dev/sdX bs=1M | grep -P '[^\x00]'
```

However, as this works with piping the *stdout*, eventually this falls out with an error saying that the operation ran out of memory. So, it's of no use.

Of course, creating a whole image of the entire disk and saving it is not an option. But, perhaps, doing that while somehow being able to skip **0x00** on the fly – that'd be one of the solutions..

Ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a device, `/dev/zero` on a linux system that always gives zero when read.

So, how about comparing your hard drive with this device:

```
cmp /dev/sdX /dev/zero
```

If all is well with zero-ing out your hard drive it will terminate with:

```
cmp: EOF on /dev/sdb
```

telling you that the two files are the same until it got to the end of the hard drive. If there is a non zero bit on the hard drive cmp will tell you where it is in the file.

If you hav the `pv` package installed then

```
pv /dev/sdX | cmp /dev/zero
```

will do the same thing with a progress bar to keep you amused while it ckecks your drive (the EOF will now be on `-` rather than `sdX` though).

Comment: Great suggestion, I will try that out (hopefully without out of memory errors as of this time), thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From https://superuser.com/a/559855/236344:

`od` will replace runs of the same thing with `*`, so you can easily use it to scan for nonzero bytes:

```
$ sudo od /dev/disk2 | head
0000000    000000  000000  000000  000000  000000  000000  000000  000000
*
234250000
```